# How to change auto wrap space

Tags: html, css

How to make those space equal? I want auto warp and `\n`'s space height to be equal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The one is the `line-heigth` parameter, the other one the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` between the text paragraphs (i.e. most likely `p` elements).

If you set the top and bottom margin of those `p`s to zero, there won't be any additional space between them.

Answer (score 0):

set a class for all the p elements that you want have same height.
for the height between two p's the you can put them in same p tag or change the p or parent box margin. also change the line-height